# Bibtex error message: I was expecting a `,'

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

I have been trying to fix my bib-tex reference file for a while now, and keep getting the same error message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
The top-level auxiliary file: _Gilead Company Analysis.aux
The style file: agsm.bst
Database file #1: ./references.bib
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 63 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : @misc{Chan2015,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 143 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : @book{Bragg2011,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 151 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : @article{Halsey2001,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 181 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : @misc{Wieczner2015,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 190 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : @misc{forbes.com2015,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 198 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : @misc{4_fda.gov_2015,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 206 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : @misc{Datamonitorhealthcare.com2015,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 214 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : @misc{Gilead.com2015,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 214 of file ./references.bib
 : @misc{Gilead.com2015
 :                     ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 222 of file ./references.bib
 : @misc{7_financial 
 :                   times_2015,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 238 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : @article{Porter2008,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 254 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : @misc{Marketrealist2015,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 262 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : @book{who2014guidelines,
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 272 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : title={{Gilead Sciences Inc. 2014 Annual Report}},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 291 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : note={Accessed on 11/10/2015},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 299 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : note={Accessed on 13/10/2015},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 307 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : note={Accessed on 28/10/2015},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 315 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : note={Accessed on 10/10/2015},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 323 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : note={Accessed on 10/10/2015},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 331 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : note={Accessed on 2015/10/10},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 339 of file ./references.bib
 : 
 : note={Accessed on 10/10/2015},
(Error may have been on previous line)
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
(There were 21 error messages)
```

Whereas I simply can not find the mistake. I can't see any `,'s missing at any lines.

Heres my bibtex file:

```
@article{Gilead.com2015,
title = {Worldwide Operations},
author = {{Gilead Sciences Inc.}},
year = {2015},
journal = {\url{http://www.gilead.com/about/worldwide-operations}},
date = {Accessed: 08/10/2015},
}

@article{Shiozaki2014,
title = {Global biotech investment trends and opportunities},
author = {Shiozaki, Eric},
year = {2014},
journal = {Australasian Biotechnology},
volume = {24},
number = {2},
}

@article{Frangioni2012,
title={Nonprofit foundations for open-source biomedical technology development},
author={Frangioni, John V},
journal={Nature biotechnology},
volume={30},
number={10},
pages={928--932},
year={2012},
publisher={Nature Publishing Group},
}

@misc{Crow2015,
author = {Crow, David and Sevastopulo, Demetri and Chon, Gina},
title = {Biotech stocks fall further as Hillary Clinton unveils drug policy},
howpublished = {\url{http://www.ft.com/intl/cms/s/0/f01b371e-6142-11e5-a28b-50226830d644.html#axzz3pDnk75lu}},
year = {2015},
note = {Accessed on 08/10/2015},
}

@misc{WorldBank2015,
title = {Health Expenditure, total (\% of GDP)},
author = {{World Bank}},
year = {2015},
howpublished = {\url{http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SH.XPD.TOTL.ZS/countries/1W-US-GB-EU-CN-JP?display=graph}},
note = {Accessed: 12/10/2015},
}

@article{UN2013,
title={World Population Ageing 2013},
author={United Natinos},
journal={Economic and Social Affairs},
pages={3--29},
year={2013},
}

@misc{Sparta2015,
title={Industries: Pharmaceuticals and Biotechnology Regulations Overview},
author={{Sparta Systems Inc.}},
year={2015},
howpublished={\url{http://www.spartasystems.com/industries/pharmaceutical-biotech/regulations-overview/},
note={Accessed: 14/10/2015},
}

@misc{Chan2015,
author={Chan, Gabriella},
title={{Andrew Robb: Australia and US close to drug patent compromise for TPP deal}},
howpublished={\url{http://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2015/oct/04/andrew-robb-australia-and-us-close-to-drug-patent-compromise-for-tpp-deal}},
year={2015},
note={Accessed on 14/10/2015},
}

@misc{Farrer2015,
author = {Farrer, Martin},
title = {From cars to cough medicine: why the Trans-Pacific Partnership matters to you},
howpublished = {\url{http://www.theguardian.com/business/2015/oct/05/from-cars-to-cough-medicine-why-the-trans-pacific-partnership-matters-to-you}},
year = {2015},
note = {Accessed on 13/10/2015},
}

@misc{Armstrong2015,
author = {Armstrong, Shiro},
title = {The race to a risky Trans-Pacific Partnership deal},
howpublished = {\url{http://www.eastasiaforum.org/2015/07/26/the-race-to-a-risky-trans-pacific-partnership-deal/}},
year = {2015},
note = {Accessed on 15/10/2015},
}

@misc{BBC2015,
author = {BBC News},
title = {Trans-Pacific free trade deal agreed creating vast partnership},
howpublished = {\url{http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-34444799}},
year = {2015},
note = {Accessed on 06/10/2015},
}

@misc{Doh2014,
author = {Department of Health},
title = {Personalised health and care 2020: a framework for action},
howpublished = {\url{https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/personalised-health-and-care-2020/using-data-and-technology-to-transform-outcomes-for-patients-and-citizens}},
year = {2014},
note = {Accessed on 07/10/2015},
}

@misc{Langreth2015,
author = {Robert Langreth},
title = {AbbVie vs. Gilead: Biotech faces price wars},
howpublished = {\url{http://www.sltrib.com/home/2040327-155/abbvie-vs-gilead-biotech-faces-price}},
year = {2015},
note = {Accessed on 11/10/2015},
}

@misc{Protiviti2015,
author = {{Protiviti Inc.}},
title = {Growing Pains: What Biotechnology Companies Transitioning to Commercialization Need to Know},
howpublished = {\url{https://www.protiviti.com/en-US/Documents/White-Papers/Industries/Biotech-Growing-Pains-whitepaper-Protiviti.pdf}},
year = {2015},
note = {Accessed on 04/10/2015},
}

@misc{Ghosh2014,
author = {Ghosh, Pallab},
title = {Big pharma takeover 'threat to science base in the UK},
howpublished = {\url{http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-27208899}},
year = {2014},
note = {Accessed on 11/10/2015},
}

@misc{Rohde2012,
author = {Rohde, David},
title = {The Swelling Middle},
howpublished = {\url{http://www.reuters.com/middle-class-infographic}},
year = {2015},
note = {Accessed on 13/10/2015},
}

@misc{ILO2015,
author={The International Labour Organisation},
title={Where will unemployment be the highest over the next five years?},
url={\url{http://www.ilo.org/global/about-the-ilo/multimedia/maps-and-charts/WCMS_336950/lang--en/index.htm},
note={Accessed on 11/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@book{Bragg2011,
title={Wiley GAAP 2012: Interpretation and Application of Generally Accepted Accounting Principles},
author={Bragg, M., Steven},
publisher={Wiley},
url={\url{https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yNgYHL3iIdkC},
year={2011},
}

@article{Halsey2001,
title={Using the residual-income stock price valuation model to teach and learn ratio analysis},
author={Halsey, Robert F.},
journal={Issues in Accounting Education},
volume={16},
number={2},
pages={257--272},
year={2001}
}

@article{Pinto2010,
title={Equity asset valuation},
author={Pinto, Jerald E and Henry, Elaine and Robinson, Thomas R and Stowe, John D},
journal={CFA Institute Investment Books},
volume={2010},
number={1},
pages={1--441},
year={2010},
publisher={CFA Institute}
}

@misc{Budwell2015,
author={Budwell, George},
title={Could This Tiny Biotech Be on Gilead Sciences M\&A Radar? --  The Motley Fool},
url={\url{http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2015/05/16/could-this-tiny-biotech-be-on-gilead-sciences-ma-r.aspx},
note={Accessed on 27/10/2015},
journal={The Motley Fool},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Wieczner2015,
author={Wieczner, Jen},
title={Gilead CEO: We are taking suggestions on companies to buy},
url={\url{http://fortune.com/2015/04/30/gilead-acquisition-targets},
note={Accessed on 27/10/2015},
journal={Fortune},
year={2015}
}

@misc{forbes.com2015,
author={Forbes.com},
title={Forbes Welcome},
url={\url{http://www.forbes.com/sites/matthewherper/2015/08/20/the-fda-is-basically-approving-everything-heres-the-data-to-prove-it},
note={Accessed on 27/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{4_fda.gov_2015, 
author={US Food and Drug Administration},
title={Summary of NDA Approvals \& Receipts, 1938 to the present},
url={\url{http://www.fda.gov/aboutfda/whatwedo/history/productregulation/summaryofndaapprovalsreceipts1938tothepresent/default.htm},
note={Accessed on 27/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Datamonitorhealthcare.com2015,
author={Datamonitorhealthcare.com},
title={New HIV drug to become leading treatment by 2016 |  Datamonitor Healthcare},
url={\url{http://www.datamonitorhealthcare.com/new-hiv-drug-to-become-leading-treatment-by-2016/},
note={Accessed on 27/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Gilead.com2015,
author={Gilead.com},
title={Gilead Sciences Announces Second Quarter 2015 Financial Results | Gilead},
url={\url{http://www.gilead.com/news/press-releases/2015/7/gilead-sciences-announces-second-quarter-2015-financial-results},
note={Accessed on 27/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{7_financial times_2015,
author={Financial Times},
title={Healthcare sector leads feverish M\&A activity - FT.com},
url={\url{http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/044d00c2-d6d4-11e4-97c3-00144feab7de.html?siteedition=uk#axzz3plwpp8uG},
note={Accessed on 27/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Reuters2015,
author={Reuters},
title={Biotech R\&D spending outpaces revenue growth: report},
url={\url{http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/06/24/us-biotech-spending-idUSKBN0EZ00H20140624},
note={Accessed on 27/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@article{Porter2008,
title={The five competitive forces that shape strategy},
author={Porter, Michael E.},
year={2008},
publisher={Harvard Business School Publishing}
}

@misc{Pollack2015,
author={Pollack, Andrew},
title={Valeant Under Investigation for Its Drug Pricing Practices},
url={\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/15/business/valeant-under-investigation-for-its-drug-pricing-practices.html?_r=0},
note={Accessed on 27/10/2015},
journal={NYtimes.com},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Marketrealist2015,
author={Marketrealist.com},
title={Gilead Sciences: Investors Overview of a Leading Biotech Company - Market Realist},
url={\url{http://marketrealist.com/2015/08/gilead-sciences-investors-overview-leading-biotech-company/},
note={Accessed on 27/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@book{who2014guidelines,
title={Guidelines for the screening, care and treatment of persons with hepatitis C infection},
author={World Health Organization and others},
year={2014},
publisher={World Health Organization}
}


@misc{Gilead2014AR,
author={{Gilead Sciences Inc.}}
title={{Gilead Sciences Inc. 2014 Annual Report}},
publisher={{Gilead Sciences Inc.}},
howpublished={\url{http://www.gilead.com/ar2014/assets/img/Gilead_2014_AR.pdf}},
note={Accessed on 16/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Amgen2014,
title={Amgen Inc., 2014 2014 Form 10-K},
author={Amgen Inc.},
howpublished={\url{http://investors.amgen.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=61656&p=irol-sec}},
note={Accessed on 16/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{GileadQ32014,
title={Gilead Sciences Inc., Q3/2014 Form 10-Q},
author={Gilead Sciences Inc.},
howpublished={\url{http://investors.gilead.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=69964&p=irol-sec}}
note={Accessed on 11/10/2015},
year={2014}
}

@misc{GileadQ42014,
title={Gilead Sciences Inc., Q4/2014 Form 10-Q},
author={Gilead Sciences Inc.},
howpublished={\url{http://investors.gilead.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=69964&p=irol-sec}}
note={Accessed on 13/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{GileadQ32015,
title={Gilead Sciences Inc., Q3/2015 Form 10-Q},
author={Gilead Sciences Inc.},
howpublished={\url{http://investors.gilead.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=69964&p=irol-sec}}
note={Accessed on 28/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Gilead2011,
title={Gilead Sciences Inc., 2011 Form 10-K},
author={Gilead Sciences Inc.},
howpublished={\url{http://investors.gilead.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=69964&p=irol-sec}}
note={Accessed on 10/10/2015},
year={2012}
}

@misc{Gilead2012,
title={Gilead Sciences Inc., 2012 Form 10-K},
author={Gilead Sciences Inc.},
howpublished={\url{http://investors.gilead.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=69964&p=irol-sec}}
note={Accessed on 10/10/2015},
year={2013}
}

@misc{Gilead2013,
title={Gilead Sciences Inc., 2013 Form 10-K},
author={Gilead Sciences Inc.},
howpublished={\url{http://investors.gilead.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=69964&p=irol-sec}}
note={Accessed on 2015/10/10},
year={2014}
}

@misc{Gilead2014,
title={Gilead Sciences Inc., 2014 Form 10-K},
author={Gilead Sciences Inc.},
howpublished={\url{http://investors.gilead.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=69964&p=irol-sec}}
note={Accessed on 10/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Pwc2015,
author={PricewaterhouseCoopers LLP},
title={Venture Capital Investing Exceeds $17 Billion For The First Time Since Q4 2000, According To The Moneytree Report},
url={\url{http://www.pwc.com/us/en/press-releases/2015/venture-capital-investing-exceeds.html}},
note={Accessed on 24/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Pwc2015b,
author={PricewaterhouseCoopers LLP},
title={Economic projections: October 2015},
howpublished={\url{http://www.pwc.com/gx/en/issues/economy/global-economy-watch/projections.html}},
year={2015},
note={Accessed on 11/10/2015},
}

@misc{Ward2015,
author={Ward, Andrew},
title={Biotech company hits crowdfunding record for life sciences - FT.com},
url={\url{http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/5d0c91d8-ae38-11e4-8d51-00144feab7de.html#axzz3RF90e8qZ}},
note={Accessed on 24/10/2015},
journal={Financial Times},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Hirschler2015,
author={Hirschler, Ben},
title={Biotech buys get pharma M\&A off to flying start in 2015},
url={\url{http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/03/05/us-pharmacyclics-m-a-abbvie-deals-idUSKBN0M11HC20150305}},
note={Accessed on 24/10/2015},
journal={Reuters},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Kollewe2015,
author={Kollewe, Julia},
title={AbbVie takes over Pharmacyclics in latest Big Pharma takeover},
url={\url{http://www.theguardian.com/business/2015/mar/05/abbvie-takes-over-pharmacyclics-in-latest-big-pharma-takeover}},
note={Accessed on 24/10/2015},
journal={The Guardian},
year={2015}
}

@article{Danzon2007,
author={Danzon, Patricia M. and Epstein, Andrew and Nicholson, Sean},
title={Mergers and acquisitions in the pharmaceutical and biotech industries},
volume={28},
number={4-5},
journal={Managerial and Decision Economics},
year={2007},
pages={307-328}
}

@article{Danzon2004,
author={Danzon, Patricia and Epstein, Andrew and Nicholson, Sean},
title={Mergers and Acquisitions in the Pharmaceutical and Biotech Industries},
url={\url{http://www.nber.org/papers/w10536}},
note={Accessed on 24/10/2015},
journal={National Bureau of Economic Research},
year={2004}
}

@misc{Balchunas2015,
author={Balchunas, Eric},
title={This Is the Best?ETF?of the Past 10 Years},
url={\url{http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-09-23/this-is-the-best-etf-of-the-past-10-years}},
note={Accessed on 24/10/2015},
journal={Bloomberg.com},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Benoy2015,
author={Benoy, Ben},
title={Hillary Clinton: Crashing Biotech in Just 21 Words},
url={\url{http://economyandmarkets.com/markets/biotech/hillary-clinton-crashing-biotech-in-just-21-words/}},
note={Accessed on 24/10/2015},
journal={Economyandmarkets.com},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Egan2015,
author={Egan, Matt},
title={Biotech bull market is dead},
url={\url{http://money.cnn.com/2015/09/29/investing/biotech-bull-market-bear-bubble/}},
note={Accessed on 24/10/2015},
journal={CNNMoney},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Nisen2015,
author={Nisen, Max},
title={Forget the tech bubble. Itís the biotech bubble you should worry about},
url={\url{http://qz.com/324939/biotech-valuation-bubble/}},
note={Accessed on 24/10/2015},
journal={Quartz},
year={2015}
}

@book{Kmrgroup2012,
author={KMR Group},
title={Annual R\&D General Metrics Study Highlights New Success Rate and Cycle Time Data},
publisher={KMR Group},
url={\url{https://kmrgroup.com/PressReleases/2012_08_08%20KMR%20PBF%20Success%20Rate%20&%20Cycle%20Time%20Press%20Release.pdf}},
note={Accessed on 24/10/2015},
year={2012}
}

@book{Marketline2015usa,
author={MarketLine Advantage},
title={Biotechnology in the United States},
publisher={MarketLine Advantage},
series={Industry Profile},
year={2015},
collection={Industry Profile}
}

@book{Marketline2015europe,
author={MarketLine Advantage},
title={Biotechnology in Europe},
publisher={MarketLine Advantage},
series={Industry Profile},
year={2015},
collection={Industry Profile}
}

@book{Marketline2015global,
author={MarketLine Advantage},
title={Global Pharmaceuticals, Biotechnology \& Life Sciences},
publisher={MarketLine Advantage},
series={Industry Profile},
year={2012},
collection={Industry Profile}
}

@book{Marketline2005global,
author={MarketLine Advantage},
title={Global Pharmaceuticals, Biotechnology \& Life Sciences},
publisher={MarketLine Advantage},
series={Industry Profile},
year={2005},
collection={Industry Profile}
}

@misc{Morningstar2015,
author={Morningstar.com},
title={IBB iShares Nasdaq Biotechnology ETF IBB Quote Price News},
url={\url{http://www.morningstar.com/etfs/XNAS/IBB/quote.html}},
note={Accessed on 28/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{Nasdaq2015,
author={The NASDAQ Group, Inc.},
title={NASDAQ Biotechnology Index},
url={\url{https://indexes.nasdaqomx.com/docs/NBI_FS.pdf}},
note={Accessed on 02/11/2015},
year={2015}
}

@book{Fda2015,
author={US Food and Drug Administration},
title={FDA approves first biosimilar product Zarxio},
publisher={US Food and Drug Administration},
url={\url{http://www.fda.gov/NewsEvents/Newsroom/PressAnnouncements/ucm436648.htm}},
note={Accessed on 28/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{18_etf_2015,
author={CNBC LLC},
title={iShares Nasdaq Biotechnology ETF - IBB - Stock Quotes},
url={\url{http://data.cnbc.com/quotes/IBB}},
note={Accessed on 28/10/2015},
year={2015}
}

@misc{cnbc.com2015,
author={CNB LLC},
title={Spdr S\&P Biotech Etf - XBI - Stock Quotes},
url={\url{http://data.cnbc.com/quotes/XBI/tab/2}},
note={Accessed on 28/10/2015},
year={2015}
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It is giving you the line numbers for the errors. Use your editor to jump to the relevant lines and correct the mistakes. You ought not have `\url{}` in e.g. the `journal` field, though. And the `url` field should not contain `\url{}` either - just the url itself.

Comment: Thanks @egreg for your comment. But I don't think that is the problem. The url was in the journal field only once, and actually not included in the error message. Also the url={\url{}} command worked fine with my other bibtex file for another project....

And going to the mentioned lines, I do not see any errors. as the line mentioned is also given in the error message, but seems not to be the one containing the error.

Comment: You need to take care of encasing all "corporate authors" in double curly braces. E.g., `author={{US Food and Drug Administration}}` in entries `4_fda.gov_2015` and `Fda2015`.

Comment: Also, as the `agsm` bibliography style uses "sentence style" for title fields, you must encase words in the `title` fields that contain uppercase letters in curly braces. Examples: Hillary, Clinton, GDP, ETF, M&A, HIV, Trans-Pacific Partnership, UK, and many many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look to the `bib` entry before the entry `Chan2015` with the first error:

```
@misc{Sparta2015,
title={Industries: Pharmaceuticals and Biotechnology Regulations Overview},
author={{Sparta Systems Inc.}},
year={2015},
howpublished={\url{http://www.spartasystems.com/industries/pharmaceutical-biotech/regulations-overview/},
note={Accessed: 14/10/2015},
}
```

There is a `}` missing at the end of the `howpublished` field!  You need one pair of `{}` for the `howpublished`, a second pair for the `\url` command: `\howpublished={\url{...}},`.

Change it to (see the `}},` at the end of `howpublished`!):

```
@misc{Sparta2015,
  title={Industries: Pharmaceuticals and Biotechnology Regulations Overview},
  author={{Sparta Systems Inc.}},
  year={2015},
  howpublished={\url{http://www.spartasystems.com/industries/pharmaceutical-biotech/regulations-overview/}},
  note={Accessed: 14/10/2015},
}
```

Now you can see, that you should check one by one the reported errors. best to do check the first error, correct it, recompile, check the next first error, ...

An second example for another error. See the entry:

```
@misc{ILO2015,
author={The International Labour Organisation},
title={Where will unemployment be the highest over the next five years?},
url={\url{http://www.ilo.org/global/about-the-ilo/multimedia/maps-and-charts/WCMS_336950/lang--en/index.htm},
note={Accessed on 11/10/2015},
year={2015}
}
```

Formal there is a closing `}` missing,  but you do not need to add command `\url` in an bib field `url`: so change it to (delete `\url{`!):

```
url={http://www.ilo.org/global/about-the-ilo/multimedia/maps-and-charts/WCMS_336950/lang--en/index.htm},
```

In the comments to your question and in the answer of @egreg you can find hints to the other errors you have in your bib file.  Please follow them and check one by one the **first** returned error in your bib file. Why the first error? It could be that this error causes following errors.  So correct the first error, compile, check and correct the now first error, compile, ...

Correct **all** errors and warning you get from your bib file!

Answer (score 3):

1. Several entries have the form `url={\url{...},` with a missing brace
2. There's a duplicate entry `Gilead.com2015`
3. The key `7_financial times_2015` contains a space, which is illegal
4. A comma is missing at the end of the `url` field in the entries `Gilead2014AR`, `GileadQ32014`, `GileadQ42014`, `GileadQ32015`, `Gilead2011`, `Gilead2012`, `Gilead2013`, and `Gilead2014`
5. The journal is missing in `Porter2008` (only a warning).