# Bib-tex error(while references)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have been trying to fix my bib-tex reference file for a while now, and keep getting the same error message:

```
@article{link:algosqr,
    I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 189 of file my_bib.bib
     :   
     :   journal={International Journal of Engineering Research and General Science},
    (Error may have been on previous line)
```

Whereas I simply can not find the mistake. I can't see any `,'s missing at any lines.

Heres my bibtex file:

```
@article{link:algosqr,
  title={Efficient Elliptic Curve Point Multiplication with Montgomery Ladder Algorithm},
  author={Aghaie, Anita}
  journal={International Journal of Engineering Research and General Science},
  year={2016},

}
```

Please help me in correcting this error

Comment: You are missing a comma after `author={Aghaie, Anita}`, you want: `author={Aghaie, Anita},`

Comment: Note that in this case the error message was impressively accurate. It indicates the `journal` line and mentions '(Error may have been on previous line)', which is exactly true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing comma in last of author name
Writing:

```
author={Aghaie, Anita},
```

Instead of

```
author={Aghaie, Anita}
```

The Error message indicate that there is problem previous line of journal.

```
journal={International Journal of Engineering Research and General Science},
    (Error may have been on previous line)
```

So, instead of change the journal line you have to change the line previous from journal
See [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276658/bibtex-error-message-i-was-expecting-a)
for more detail of such error. As mentioned by moewe

Comment: Now you want credit for somebody else reading your error message for you? It is not very nice to ask for help and then claim the credit for a solution provided by somebody else in response. It would be better to ask moewe to write an answer that you could accept - credit where credit is due.